# What is the exact value of $\arctan \left( 7 \cdot \frac{\sqrt 3} 2 \right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm completely lost on how you're supposed to find this. I'm aware of the standard unit circle values. I've checked online services that claim to be capable of producing exact answers, including WA and maple; they all return floating point approximations.

(Here, "exact" is being used to mean a solution in terms of $\pi$, square roots, and/or integer ratios, as necessary.)

Comment: Is there a reason you think there is such an exact answer?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZpCQZZU.png

Comment: $\arctan\left(\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$ is neither an algebraic number (over $\mathbb{Q}$) or an algebraic number times $\pi$. Faulty question.

Comment: So the software authors are asking for an impossible solution. Great.

Comment: @srcs: I am sorry to carry bad news :/

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Out of curiosity, how do you know that it's not algebraic (times $\pi$)?

Comment: @DanielFischer: The fact it is not algebraic follows from Gauss' continued fraction. The fact it is not $\pi\cdot x$ with $x$ algebraic follows by applying the multiplication formulas for the tangent function, and recalling that $\pi = 3\arctan(\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Anyway, a pretty accurate approximation of such number is $\frac{885074212}{628911441}$ (from the continued fraction, of course).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. Interesting.

Comment: Well, I hit similar question and got one that worked out okay. I'll bookmark this and ask my professor about it tomorrow.

Comment: If it said arcsin or arccos, it would be routine.  Might "tan" be a typo? $\qquad$

Comment: Definitely not. Followed along with the given example. Unless you mean there was a typo in the program itself, which is unlikely. I'm guessing the key to the problem is that the argument is an integer multiple of sqrt(3)/2.